# Use MySql database for userData, and NoSql(MongoDB) for messagges

Tags: php, mysql, nosql

I've done a lot of research but didn't find a proper answer.

I know the difference between the two options but still got questions..

Is it a good idea to store user datas, bans, etc in a MySQL Database and use NoSQL for messages?

Like if XY send a message to ZS then save it in my MySQL database

```
id: 1
userID_1: 21
userID_2: 45
secureKey: 3f3AbO39Vl1
```

and in the NoSQL database save the messages like

```
userID_1: 21
userID_2: 45
secureKey: 3f3AbO39Vl1
messages: [messages..]
```

Or in longer perspectives it is better to use NoSQL everywhere because it can expand without limits.. ?

Comment: There is no "proper" answer to this question. It depends, on lots of things.

Comment: I know there's no "proper" answer. I just would like to hear some opinions